# Aspire E1-572 doesn't detect RAM

Tags: memory, acer-aspire, ddr3

I have an Acer Aspire E1-572 and just purchased a Kingston KVR13S9S8/4 to upgrade it to 8GB RAM but the system doesn't detect the new memory.

The info about the original RAM that came with the laptop is as follows (# dmidecode -t 17):

```
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x000F
Error Information Handle: No Error
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 4096 MB
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: None
Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
Bank Locator: BANK 2
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: 1600 MHz
Manufacturer: 0114
Serial Number: 04211349
Asset Tag: 9876543210
Part Number: SF564128CJ8NWMNSEG
Rank: 1
Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
Minimum Voltage: 1.35 V
Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
Configured Voltage: 1.35 V
```

Comment: Have you updated the computer's BIOS? Does the computer boot with the new memory installed?

Comment: The answer to both questions is "no", so I guess I will have to buy a 1.35V one, right?

Comment: You should upgrade the BIOS first, because that's easier.

Comment: Also, don't rule out contacting Acer Support. I upgraded the RAM in an HP some years ago, and they had to direct me to a non-standard BIOS flash in order to detect the additional memory.

Comment: Got it. I usually tell people to go check with the support first and didn't know why I didn't do it. Long story short, they are not compatible. The memory shipped is 1600Mhz with 1.35V (DDR3**L**) tension. The new one is 1333Mhz 1.5V. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspire E1-572 does not support regular DDR3 (1.5v) memory.

Supported Memory here: http://www.memorystock.com/memory/AcerAspireE1572.html

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer. More details about the issue, please refer to the comments under the main thread.